# Finding row causing error in type conversion in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-conversion

I am trying to cast a column as `smalldatetime` from `varchar`. There are some rows containing errors, how can I find them?

```
SELECT 
    PA.EAR_TAG 
    ,ISNULL(B.DISPOSAL_DATE, H.DISPOSAL_DATE) as HB_Date
    ,Y.[DATE OF MOVEMENT] as Y_Date
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY, ISNULL(B.DISPOSAL_DATE, H.DISPOSAL_DATE), cast(Y.[DATE OF MOVEMENT] as smalldatetime))
FROM
    DairyTelomere.dbo.PROJECT_ANIMALS AS PA
LEFT JOIN 
    Langhill.dbo.YOUNG_STOCK_BULL AS B ON Pa.EAR_TAG = B.EAR_TAG
LEFT JOIN      
    Langhill.dbo.YOUNG_STOCK_HEIFER AS H ON PA.EAR_TAG = H.EAR_TAG
LEFT JOIN      
    DairyTelomere.dbo.Young_Stock_culls AS Y ON PA.EAR_TAG = Y.Ear_Tag
```

The error I get is:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I know that if the column was in a date format I could check it by using `ISDATE()` but unfortunately I can't change the column type (don't have permissions).

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the [isdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get a list of all the ones that are not converting for you. You dont need to change the column type to use this so i am confused by your statement

> if the column was in a date format I could check it by using ISDATE() but unfortunately I can't change the column type (don't have permissions)

Will help more if you can clarify but this query should get you a list of rows that have bad date values.

```
select table.date_as_varchar
from table
where isdate(table.date_as_varchar) = 0
```

Comment: @branwen85, happy to help. If you need help figuring a way to handle for the bad dates if you open another question with some samples of the bad dates and good dates just post a link to the question here and ill see if i can help further

Comment: Good answer assuming that there is a function like `ISDATE` around. But let's say that you have numeric data and we know that ISNUMERIC isn't to be trusted (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC%28%29/71512/)? I like `TRY_CAST` in general for this sort of thing. But that isn't to take away from your solution; it's perfectly serviceable here.

Answer (score 7):

adding to @workabyte answer you can also try using `TRY_PARSE`, `TRY_CAST` OR `TRY_CONVERT`, all of them return `NULL` if the conversion failed, that way you can know wich rows caused the error.

**TRY_PARSE**

as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql) says:

> Use TRY_PARSE only for converting from string to date/time and number
>   types. For general type conversions, continue to use CAST or CONVERT.
>   Keep in mind that there is a certain performance overhead in parsing
>   the string value.

**Usage example:**

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE(your_date  AS DATETIME USING 'es-ES') as date
FROM your_table
```

`es-ES` is a culture parameter,different culture paramaters yield different results in your conversions, you can find the full list of parameters in the documentation

**TRY_CONVERT**

as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) says:

> TRY_CONVERT takes the value passed to it and tries to convert it to
>   the specified data_type. If the cast succeeds, TRY_CONVERT returns the
>   value as the specified data_type; if an error occurs, null is
>   returned. However if you request a conversion that is explicitly not
>   permitted, then TRY_CONVERT fails with an error.

**Usage example:**

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME,your_date,103) as date
FROM your_table
```

The 103 being the style/format of the date you are converting, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) you can find a list of the formats avaliable

**TRY_CAST**

as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) says:

> TRY_CAST takes the value passed to it and tries to convert it to the
>   specified data_type. If the cast succeeds, TRY_CAST returns the value
>   as the specified data_type; if an error occurs, null is returned.
>   However if you request a conversion that is explicitly not permitted,
>   then TRY_CAST fails with an error.

**Usage example:**

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(your_date AS DATETIME) as date
FROM your_table
```